# Tool to convert C structure to ctypes.Structure?

Tags: python, structure, ctypes

I spend most the time when I work with ctypes on converting C structures to ctypes.Structure, and double the work to convert typedef'ed data types if it's some Windows structures. It's monotonous and boring process.

Is there some available tool to do it automatically?, I imagine that I give it the structure and the include header and it generates ctypes.Structure for me.

Comment: You may want to try out http://cffi.readthedocs.org/ .

Comment: I came across this one: https://github.com/davidjamesca/ctypesgen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no experience with it myself, but the [ctypes code generator](http://starship.python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/old/codegen.html) looks a lot like what you are looking for:

> The generator converts declarations in C header files into executable
>   Python code: enums, structs, unions, function declarations, com
>   interfaces, and preprocessor definitions.

It's available from the [svn repo](http://svn.python.org/projects/ctypes/trunk/ctypeslib/). Note that the last commit was in 2009, so your mileage may vary.